# operator>>(,) overload behaving in a surprising way

Tags: c++, overloading

Well, maybe it is not so surprising. Stackoverflow has a lot of questions and contributions to that point. Only they are not EXACTLY to the point.

Here an extract from the C++ standard (in fact a c++14 draft, but I assume the passage is the same in current C++11 standard):

> An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or be a non-member function that has
>   at least one parameter whose type is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an
>   enumeration. It is not possible to change the precedence, grouping, or number of operands of operators.
>   The meaning of the operators =, (unary) &, and , (comma), predefined for each type, can be changed for
>   specific class and enumeration types by defining operator functions that implement these operators. Operator
>   functions are inherited in the same manner as other base class functions.

Thus, to my understanding, it is perfectly legal to have 1 class type and one non-class type as parameters to operator>>(,). The standard does not say "The first" or "The second" parameter. Just "One" of them must be a class type.

Here a code snippet which surprises me:

```
int operator>> ( int v, std::function<int(int)> transformer )
{
    int v1 = transformer(v);
    DGS::CLogger::GetLogger()->Log<int>(&IntFormatter, v1 );
    return v1;
}
static int DoItLoggedAndCompact( int value )
{
    int x = operator>>( operator>>(value, DoIt) , AnotherIntCalculation ); // compiles and works!
    return x;
// The following line produces (with clang++):
// error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'int (*)(int)')
//      return value >> DoIt >> AnotherIntCalculation; : 
}
```

Please note that "A function pointer is not a class type", while being a correct statement, is not a comprehensive answer. As you see in the rewritten code starting with `int x = ...` and the definition of operator>> second parameter, the function pointer is silently converted to a std::function.

I cannot find anywhere in the standard a passage which states, that the conversion rules for those two (allegedly) synonymous forms differ.

So, is this a compiler bug, a community wide over-interpretation of the C++ specification or...something else we see here? Or simply some stupid oversight on my part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

But **"A function pointer is not a class type"** *is* the correct answer.

There's the following note in clause 13.6:

> operator overload resolution occurs only when an operand expression originally has class
>   or enumeration type

The normative rule is in 13.3.1.2 (emphasis mine):

> If no operand of an operator in an expression has a type that is a class or an enumeration,  the operator is assumed to be a built-in operator and interpreted according to Clause 5.
>
> **If either operand has a type that is a class or an enumeration**, a user-deﬁned operator function might be declared that implements this operator or a user-deﬁned conversion can be necessary to convert the operand to a type that is appropriate for a built-in operator.  In this case, overload resolution is used to determine which  operator  function  or  built-in  operator  is  to  be  invoked  to  implement  the  operator.   Therefore,  **the operator notation is first transformed to the equivalent function-call notation** as summarized in Table 11.

The forms are synonymous only when one of the operands is a class type.  Since neither one is here, the rewrite as `operator>>()` doesn't occur.

Comment: Did you mean `operator>>` instead of `operator<<`?

Comment: @MarkB: Yes, thanks, although the rule applies to all of them.

Comment: I assume he meant operator>> and it is but a typo. Yet, while I accept the answer, I cannot help but think that the specification hints to a deeper problem. Why would the (convertible) type of an operand have an impact? To my taste, the two forms should always be synonymous and the rewrite from the short to the longer form should take place BEFORE operand types are taken into consideration.

Comment: @user2225104: Then every usage would become ambiguous.  There's virtually no built-in type that can't convert to *something* of class type.  Anyway, you asked whether it was a compiler bug, and it isn't; the Standard is clear that this is the required behavior.

Comment: @user2225104 you cannot do that before operand types are taken into consideration: to what do you convert? You can have unlimited user-types can be constructed from a built-in type (or a built-in type  can be converted to an unlimited class types)

Comment: The same should then apply to the other form. I consider the short form "syntactic sugar" and sugar should not pour salt into your dishes ;)

Comment: @user2225104: The current rules provide compatibility with C.  C doesn't have class types, so C++ can do anything with expressions involving class types without breaking anything.  But expressions without class types already have meaning in C, and C++ strives to keep that meaning.  Injecting overload resolution into that would definitely change the behavior of perfectly good C code.

Comment: @BenVoigt : A valid point, even though not many would (intentionally) shift an integer to the right, the function address of a function pointer times. Maybe C specification could be narrowed and people would find tons of bugs in their code, such as forgotten (). ;)

Comment: @user2225104: Currently it gives a perfectly reasonable error message.  Having it rewrite to function-call form and start converting operands would be more likely to hide errors, not less.

Comment: On a side note: I was trying to configure my clang and also a 4.8.x gcc to become an "oldest possible" compiler, only compiling C code (not C++) and tried to "forget" the (), I.e. shift an integral value to the right by the address of a function and... it never compiled. So C legacy is obviously NOT the reason, this inconvenience is burdened upon us.

Comment: @user2225104: Continuing to generate the same error for the same datatypes is part of backward compatibility.

Comment: @BenVoigt : The c++ keyword ``class`` also produces a compiler error in C-code compiled with a C-compiler. I fail to see the point here.

Comment: @user2225104: Is your point that because compatibility is not 100%, that it is not worth trying to get 99.9%?  If so, you're wrong, many developers appreciate near-perfect compatibility.  If you have a different point, please explain.

Comment: @BenVoigt : Indeed I do. The construct discussed in this post would allow for great code. Just because someone tries to - as you mused - compile some legacy C code with a C++ compiler, expecting their code NOT to compile (errm...) ... progress is blocked. I doubt there is a majority of people who want code not to compile just for the not-compiling sake of it.

Comment: @user2225104: Unless I am mistaken, you have proposed overload resolution for operators in all expressions, not just where the operands have class type.  That does not only affect C code which fails to compile, it also changes the meaning of good and working C code.  So the language committee will never approve it.  You could have a rule that "If the built-in operators generate an error, then use overload resolution" but that would be very confusing and complicated and people would still complain when their overload wasn't used (because the builtin operator *did* compile)

Comment: @user2225104: The answer is that: "Overloading happens if at least one operand has class type" is a rule which is simple and easy-to-understand, and does not break any C code.  If you think you can write a rule just as good, first try writing it, then make a proposal to change the language.  But be prepared to be told that (1) your rule isn't simple or (2) it changes the behavior of code A, B, and C which are working fine under the current rules

Comment: Lets assume the lexeme ">>" would always the treated as operator>>() and then the function would be optimized away again in the legacy cases. Do you really think that would break existing code?

Comment: I know it would change the meaning of existing working code, depending on what overloads you write.