# Implicit type conversion from initialization list compiles in one case but does not in another

Tags: c++, c++11

I defined the following class:

```
class A {
    int a;
public:
    A(int _a = 0) :a(_a){}
    A(initializer_list<int> il) :a(il.size()){}
    friend A operator+(const A& a1, const A& a2);
};
A operator+(const A& a1, const A& a2){ return A(); }
```

The following client code

```
A a;
operator+(a,{3, 4, 5});
```

can compile, but the following

```
A a;
a + {3, 4, 5};
```

can not compile. The error message is "`error C2059: syntax error : '{'`" and "`error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'`".

Both two client codes try to do the implicit type conversion, from initialization list `{3,4,5}` to `class A`, but the first succeeds while the second snippet fails. I can not understand why.

Can you explain it?

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2013 Update 4.

[Edit]
Here is a follow up, after reading the comments and other related materials. I think my question can now be reduced to the following:
I got it that brace-init-list is not allowed in the RHS of an binary expression, and also that it IS allowed in a function call. The thing is, I think the binary expression, say, `arg1 + arg2` is converted internally by the compiler to a function call `operator+ (arg1, arg2)`, especially when arg1 is a class type. So at this point, there is no difference between binary expression and function call. As a result, the only explanation I can figure out is that there is a preventing rule applied before such a binary-expression-to-function-call conversion, that checks particularly whether the second argument is a brace-init-list or not. If it is, conversion to an equivalent function call will be forbidden and an error is produced. I wonder if these conjectures are real and if it is, is it written somewhere specifically in the C++ standard? Thank everyone who participated in my question.

Comment: That reminds me somehow of an operator << problem I had a while ago. Somehow and for some operators, the standard prohibits implicit type conversions of arguments. The lesson I learned back then is: Screw "syntactic sugar".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826824/operator-overload-behaving-in-a-surprising-way   <<-- the answers there might also apply to your question somehow

Comment: Answer is: {3,4,5} is not a class type. Hence no implicit conversion.

Comment: @user2225104: how do you explain the first code then? it is converted inside C++11 implicitly from initialization list to initializer_list<int>.

Comment: Syntactically, `{3, 4, 5}` is a *braced-init-list*. A *braced-init-list* is not an expression; the syntax only allows it in a limited number of places, it cannot appear everywhere an integer literal may appear, say. In particular, it's allowed as an argument to a function call, and explicitly allowed on the right hand side of an assignment operator (**5.18/9**), but not any other operators.

Comment: Same case as in my question. ``operator+(arg1,arg2)`` does not have the same conversion rules applied as ``arg1 + arg2``.

Comment: But isn't `arg1 + arg2` exactly the same thing as `operator+(arg1,arg2)`? All rules that apply to function call in form of `operator+(arg1,arg2)` should be applied to `arg1 + arg2` because they are the same thing to a compiler -- compiler first convert `arg1 + arg2` to `operator+(arg1,arg2)` and then applies grammar rules, but when applying, there has been no difference between these two forms. Isn't it?

Comment: @user280121 The are not the same to the syntax parser. Syntax parsing is complex, and `arg1 + arg2` may not be interpreted as `operator+(arg1,arg2)`.

Comment: But this equivalence IS what most C++ textbooks claim to be (usually at the beginning of the chapter devoted to overloaded operators for classes).

Comment: @Lingxi: This is an example: http://i61.tinypic.com/2vkc7lc.png. The text clearly says they are equivalent.

Comment: Books (most books, maybe) are there to lead you in and give you a general idea. They are not meant to be exact and formal. This is true even for cppreference. Only the standard is the definite reference.

Comment: There is a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11420448/951890

Comment: @Vaughn Cato: Yeah, that's really a good link. Someone (mfontanini in the comment) touched the root of the question, but all of a sudden, like in this question, everyone becomes silent, or carefully keeps away from that root. I will add this root thing in my question. Also I will read the draft/discussion paper N2215 by Stroustrup to have a concrete understanding of what "chaos" or "kludge" is, but that will certainly take me quite a while. A good news is that the summer break is near :-).

Answer (score 3):

The error message generated by clang is quite clear:

`error: initializer list cannot be used on the right hand side of operator '+'`

Looking into the C++11 standard, I find this (8.5.4/1 [dcl.init.list]):

> Note: List-initialization can be used
>
> - as the initializer in a variable definition (8.5)
> - as the initializer in a new expression (5.3.4)
> - in a return statement (6.6.3)
> - as a function argument (5.2.2)
> - as a subscript (5.2.1)
> - as an argument to a constructor invocation (8.5, 5.2.3)
> - as an initializer for a non-static data member (9.2)
> - in a mem-initializer (12.6.2)
> - on the right-hand side of an assignment (5.17)

So I guess braced-init-list can only be used in the cases listed above. `operator+(a, {1, 2, 3})` works because of case 4. `a = {1, 2, 3}` works because of the last case. But nothing is mentioned about `a + {1, 2, 3}`. So no.

Comment: But why can't we explain `a + {1, 2, 3}` as `operator+(a, {1, 2, 3})` and apply the case 4? This conversion (from `arg1+arg2` to `operator+(arg1,arg2)`) is an ordinary concept of overloaded operator definition for classes.

Comment: @user280121 Well, I'm not a compiler writer. So I cannot give you an exact answer. C++ parsing is complex. Just interpret `a + {1, 2, 3}` to `operator+(a, {1, 2, 3})`? While it sounds reasonable to us common folks as C++ users, it is not as simple as that to compiler writers who know what is really going on under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to look in the standard to find out the reason why it is not allowed to write `expression + braced-init-list` and the first I have found is a comment in an example

§5.1.2 (4)

> a braced-init-list is not an expression

and it does not fulfill the requirements for a primary-expression. But it can be used in a postfix-expression:

```
postfix-expression:
    simple-type-specifier braced-init-list
    typename-specifier braced-init-list
```

Binary operators like `+` expect expressions to the left and right and thus, `expression + braced-init-list` does not fit into the c++-grammer.

But a braced-init-list can appear on the right-hand side of an assignment, since it expects an initializer-clause:

```
assignment-expression:
    logical-or-expression assignment-operator initializer-clause
initializer-clause:
    assignment-expression
    braced-init-list
```

Thus, you could rewrite your example using a operator+=:

```
A operator+=(A& a1, const A& a2){ return A(); }
int main() {
    A a;
    a + A{3, 4, 5};
    a += {3, 4, 5};
}
```